# How to handle autocomplete in Angular.JS from JSON feed

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-directive

I am working on implementing autocomplete for a text box similar to what is done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/light/). The main difference being I want mine to come from a service returning a list. Here is the code I use...

```
  //How I would like it to work...
  $scope.search=function(query){
    $http.get('/product/query/name%3A'+query+'*').success(function(data){
      // For a data is ["a","a1"]
      $scope.names = data;
    })
  }
  //Trying to get it to work by not using the ng-change event but still no dice
  $http.get('/product/query/name%3A*').success(function(data){
      //Data when printed does in fact match the ["a","a1", "b"]
      $scope.names = data;
  });
  //finally this DOES work but not dynamic
  $scope.names =["a","a1", "b"];
```

Anyone able to provide some insight as to what I am missing?

Comment: try to create a factory and do the http call from factory and then assign the results to scope.name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `typeahead` which is part of [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) library

http://plnkr.co/edit/08vi4ncjLrWfUBjWrZKS?p=preview

[image]

Comment: just an FYI, plunker link is no good now, they use a post to send code to plunker when you click "edit in plunker"

Comment: I will take a look thanks, any idea why this situation is failing?

Comment: So I tried this out and I am about ready to give the check. The last thing I am struggling with is how would I use an attribute. For example if I need a name and an ID to map back to the object? This example just pushes a single value. So in this sample I need the formatted address along with the address id

Comment: Would something like typeahead="address.name for address in getLocation($viewValue)" work?

Comment: @Jackie, here's a new plunk with your desires :) 
http://plnkr.co/edit/5OeZ7e7Q6jYP2LkKN1jm?p=preview